# Change Mui Select value on button Click using react hook form in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I want to change the value on button click using SetValue function of react-hook-form using useForm().

Child component

```
import { MenuItem, Select, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { RegisterOptions, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

const RHFSelect= ({name,label, options,required,defaultValue, multiple}) => {
  const {register, unregister,clearErrors,setValue,formState: { errors }} = 
   useFormContext()
  useEffect(() => {return () => {unregister(name)}}, [])
  return (
    <div> <Typography>{label}</Typography>
      <Select {...register(name)} defaultValue={defaultValue} multiple={multiple}>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        {options.map((ele: any) => (
            <MenuItem key={ele?.id} value={ele?.value}>{ele?.label}</MenuItem>
          ))}</Select>      </div>)};
export default RHFSelect;
```

button Click Function

```
const onButtonClick= (data: any) => {   
    setValue("residenceType", "own");   
    setValue("Cities", ["delhi","mumbai"]);    
  };
```

options

```
const residenceOptions = [{ id: 1, label: "Rented", value: "rented" },{ id: 2, label: "Own", value: "own" }]

const citiesOptions = [{ id: 1, label: "Del;hi", value: "delhi" },{ id: 2, label: "Mumbai", value: "mumbai" }, { id: 3, label: "Hyderabad", value: "hyderabad" }]
```

parent Component

```
const ParentComp = ()=>{
const methods = useForm();  
const { setValue } = methods;
return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}><div>
 <RHFTest label="Residence Type" name="residenceType"  options={residenceOptions }
      defaultValue="rented" multiple={false} />
<RHFTest label="Cities" name="cities" options={citiesOptions}
          defaultValue={["mumbai"]} multiple={ true} />       
        <button onClick={onButtonClick}> set</button>
        <button onClick={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}> Submit</button> </div> </FormProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: What is the question? You already have a function to do that onButtonClick. What is wrong?

Comment: It is not chnaging the value on button click,, iwrote function on button, pls check

Comment: Some debugging details? what is the form state? what useWatch() returns? If the form has the right state, probably the mui select expects to work with a controller. https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller

Comment: it is changing the value but not displaying in select field

Comment: Probably you have to transform "register" into this  react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller. Mui inputs are controlled